# How do I nest models using a form_tag in Rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've got a form to add SaleQualifiers to my app - which works fine when I'm using:

`<%= form_for(@sale_qualifier, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'sale_qualifier'}, remote: true) do |f| %>`

The problem with `form_for` is that I want to put the form inline within a table row in my view - so as a method to get around that I'm now using:

`<%= form_tag('/sale_qualifiers', method: :post, remote: true) do -%>
    <%= fields_for :sale_qualifier do |ff| %>`

This is working fine for most of the fields I need to generate, but I've got a nested attribute field for Answer (Answer belongs_to SaleQualifier). This is not generating the right field names in the view, and as a result when I go to save the object this way I don't capture the answer_attributes.

Here's the full working form using form_for:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <%= form_for(@sale_qualifier, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'sale_qualifier'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @sale_qualifier.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@sale_qualifier.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this answer from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @sale_qualifier.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2><%= @question.question_text %></h2>
    <% unless @question.id == 1 %>
      <p><%= link_to('Back', edit_sale_qualifier_path(id: @prior_sale_qualifier), data: { disable_with: "Loading..." }, :remote => true) %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %>
    </div>
    <% unless @question.id == 1 %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.hidden_field :prior_question_id, :value => @prior_question_id %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answer do |answer| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <% if @question.answer_type == 'Text Field' %>
        <%= answer.text_area :answer_text, :placeholder => "Enter your answer", :class => "form-control"%>
      <% end %>
      <% if @question.answer_type == 'Datetime' %>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' data-date-format="YY.MM.DD">
          <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control", data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, :placeholder => "YYYY/MM/DD" %>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
           </span>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if @question.answer_type == 'Boolean' %>
        <%= answer.select :answer_text, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]] %>
      <% end %>
      <% if @question.answer_type == 'Update' || @question.answer_type == 'Result' %>
        <%= answer.hidden_field :answer_text, :value => "Updated" %>
      <% end %>
      <span class="warning-block"></span>
      <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <% end %>
      <% if @question.answer_type == 'Update' || @question.answer_type == 'Result' %>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Done", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, autocomplete: 'off' %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, autocomplete: 'off' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code which does not work using form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag('/sale_qualifiers', method: :post, remote: true) do -%>
 <%= fields_for :sale_qualifier do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
  <%= ff.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= @question.question_text %></td>
    <td>
        <%= ff.fields_for :answer do |answer| %>
        <% if @question.answer_type == 'Text Field' %>
          <%= answer.text_area :answer_text%>
        <% end %>
        <% if @question.answer_type == 'Datetime' %>
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' data-date-format="YY.MM.DD">
            <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control", data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, :placeholder => "YYYY/MM/DD" %>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
             </div>
        <% end %>
        <% if @question.answer_type == 'Boolean' %>
          <%= answer.select :answer_text, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]] %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= ff.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, autocomplete: 'off' %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>     
<% end %>
```

For completeness, the issue I'm having is that the generated html for the working code creates the following field:

```
textarea id="sale_qualifier_answer_attributes_answer_text" name="sale_qualifier[answer_attributes][answer_text]"
```

The broken code creates the following html:

```
Textarea id="sale_qualifier_answer_answer_text" name="sale_qualifier[answer][answer_text]"
```

So how can I get the html output to show "sale_qualifier[answer_attributes][answer_text]" rather than "sale_qualifier[answer][answer_text]" in this instance using form_tag?

Comment: try 'ff.fields_for :answer_attributes do |answer|'

Comment: @mgidea - thanks, that works well. If you want to add that as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In multiple nested forms the fields_for tag will be called against
>   right parent and attributes conventions should be followed right otherwise 
>   it renders the form attributes wrong and results in errors.

```
<%= form_tag('/sale_qualifiers', method: :post, remote: true) do -%>
 <%= fields_for :sale_qualifier do |ff| %>   
   <%= ff.fields_for :answer_attributes do |answer| %>
```

Above flow will be the right one & will generate attributes as they should be.